# Need help with thermostat wiring

Tags: wiring, thermostat, replacement

I am trying to change from an American Standard AYSTAT655 to a Honeywell RTH8560D but wiring does not match anything in the Honeywell manual.  Anyone able to assist?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both the thermostat and control-board ends?

Comment: Also post system type (heat only, heat/AC, heat pump)?